# Link opens new window and loads new page on parent window

Tags: javascript, onclick, hyperlink, popupwindow

Okay I don't know if this sounds confusing but:
I want to be able to click a link that opens a new popup window and at the same time also loads a new (and different) page on the parent window.

What I have right now:

```
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('page2.html');" onClick="location.href='page3.html';">Click here</a>



<script type="text/javascript">

function newPopup(url) {
popupWindow=window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')}</script>
```

The onclick works but it doesn't open a new popup window. When I take out the onclick, the popup window works. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: Java & Javascript are entirely separate languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flipping the href and onclick - onclick happens before the href is evaluated/used.

```
<a href="page3.html" onclick="newPopup('page2.html');">Click here</a>
```

When clicked, it should open the popup because of the onclick, then naturally navigate to "page2.html".

Comment: Aren't `onclick` and `href` mutually-exclusive?

Comment: Ah! This worked! Thank you so much! And to think it was something so simple. Now I can call it a day. Thanks again :)

Comment: @jpaugh I'm not sure what you mean. When you click an anchor, the normal events occur (like a mousedown, mouseup, click, etc.), and as long as the event isnt prevented, the href is evaluated.

Comment: @kevinfeng make sure to accept his answer, so he gets credit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding onClick, you can add

window.location.href = "page3.html"

In your newPopup function, along with opening a popup.